# Use text from file

Tags: python

I have a problem when I want to extract some labels from file. I'm  talking about 2000 labels, and I would like to use them from file and give them some size characteristic.

```
with open("filename") as f:
    content = f.readlines()

nsize= { "Mary": 1, "John": 1, "Jack": 1, "Ted": 5 }
```

this is example for 4 labels. I need it for all 2000. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Sorry - but I don't actually understand what your question is... How do the labels, a line in a file, and a size characteristic link together? More context please?

Comment: Please copy paste part of the file.

Comment: Its fine now. I found solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    nsize = {el.strip(): len(el.strip()) for el in f}
```

This takes each line in `f`, `strips()` away whitespace, turns it into the key and the length of the label as the value.

If you meant to *count* them, use [`collection.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("filename") as f:
    nsize = Counter(el.strip() for el in f)
```

This takes each label from the file (again, `strip()`ing away extra whitespace), and the `Counter` dict will give you a count for each label in the file (so if label `foo` appears twice, `nsize['foo']` is 2).

Comment: I will note though - shouldn't it just be `Counter(el.strip() for el in f)` ?

Comment: @JonClements: Oopsie, skipped over the documentation a tad too fast there. Corrected.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you psychic? How did you know what he wanted?

Comment: @kojiro: Got lucky. There were two options I could think of, put them both in. Not certain still which one it was that helped..